# Dynamically sized data types in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, data-structures, c++14

In C++, I've a scenario in which the caller function would send the rows of multiple tables as parameters. And teh callee function needs to store these rows in some data structure.
I need to use a dynamically sized data structure as the size of the rows of each table might be different.

```
//CALLEE CODE: vector Row here holds the elements of the table, like Row[0] is 1st column of this row, Row[1] - 2nd columns of this row and so on.
Size of this Row might change based on the no: of columns in the table. Hence, I need to use a dynamically sized data structure vector. 
void FillTable(Vector Row, bool newTable) 
{
    if(newTable) // means caller is passing rows of a new table, hence no: of 
    Cols might change
    {
    Create a 2D vector called Table which can hold the rows.
     Now Assign each Row to the 2D vector.
    }
    else
    {
         just Assign the row to existing 2D vecttor.
    }
}

CALLER CODE:

.................

FillTable(RowOfATable, true);
while(Keep passing rows for this table)
{
FillTable(RowOfATable, false);
}

FillTable(RowOfATable, true);
while(Keep passing rows for this 2nd table)
{
FillTable(RowOfATable, false);
}
```

My question is is vector the right data structure to be used in C++ or is there a better way to do this in c++ like any container etc ? I need to make this OS agnostic to run on win, linux, mac, android.

Comment: `std::vector` should be the default container you try, yes

Comment: it is very unclear what you're asking. Separate the explanation from the example code. Don't post a barely parseable mixture of C++ and pseudocode. Post pseudocode that actually indicates the desired result. And besides, why _wouldn't_ you use `vector`? Just use the Standard containers that fit the task until you find a good reason not to use them. It should be your default to trust the stdlib and require justification to stop using it, not the opposite.

Comment: @codeLover: please **edit your question** to improve it a lot

Comment: Don't over-optimize.  If vector looks like it will work, just do it.  If the result is messy in some way, post that code here and explain what you want different.  It'll be much easier to communicate on the basis of existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. As commented by [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller), you probably want to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (since it is part of *standard* C++14 & C++11, you'll get it on any standard conforming compiler). Prefer [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Alternatively, you could use [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) and define a higher-order member function which takes a closure as argument and iterates (e.g. on every row) till that closure returns `false`. You'll generally pass a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) when invoking your higher-order member function.

<sup>(I don't know what your `Vector` is, so I can't give an easy example; however...)</sup>

Here is an example which adds to a given `std::set<std::string> setstr` every element in a `std::vector<std::string> vecstr` till a function `predicate` returns true:

```
void do_every_until (std::set<std::string>& setstr,
                     const std::vector<std::string>& vecstr,
                     std::function<bool(const std::string&)> predicate) {
  for (auto str : setstr) {
     if (predicate(str)) 
        return;
     setstr.insert(str);
  }
}
```

and here is an example of usage:

```
std::set<std::string> mysetstr;
std::vector<std::string> myvecstr = something();
do_every_until(mysetstr, myvecstr,
               [&](const std::string& curstr) {
                  // stop iterating when curstr is empty or after K
                  if (curstr.size() == 0 || curstr[0] >= 'K') 
                     return true;
                  // otherwise, add to set
                  mysetstr.insert(curstr);
                  return false;});
```

At last, you could define some [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) in your `Row` data structure. With care you might be able to use [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) on it (by defining appropriate `begin` and `end` member functions in `Row`).

Comment: Is this any different than using a 2D vector like std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> table;  NOw i can just recive rows of type vector and just insert them to the 2D vector table. ?

Comment: I don't know. Notice that a 2D vector like `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` is not a matrix of `std::string`-s, but a vector of vectors of various sizes.